# how to know which c++ version is uesd when use -lstdc++ to build cpp file

Tags: c++, gcc, build

I need to use gcc to build c++ files and gcc command is like "gcc -g test.cpp -lstdc++ -o out". How can i know which c++ version is used to build test.cpp?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `gcc -lstdc++`, use `g++` instead. The used C++ version can be seen in the output of `g++ --version`. `gcc --version` shows the same output

Comment: Yes, i know. But "gcc -lstdc++" which is used in our existed project. g++ and gcc version is 4.8.3 which support c++11. But i found in fact this project used c99 and c++98 syntax, and not support c++11.

Comment: or another question is how to use gcc to build c++11?  I hit issue "cc1: error: command line option '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]". It seems gcc cannot build c++11.

Comment: This particular error tells you that you cannot set standard to C++11 when compiling with C compiler gcc. It accepts own command line options, for example -std=c11. Use g++. You can reconfigure your existing project.